# Dplyr filter with condition

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have this df

```
ID CODE
A  45676
B  87898
B  89998
A  45688
A  45556
```

I would like to get this df

```
ID CODE    CODE_SUB
A  45676   76
B  87898   NA
B  89998   NA
A  45688   88
A  45556   56
```

CODE_SUB is last two characters from CODE with condition ID == A

I used this code

```
mutate(CODE_SUB = substr(which (df$ID == "A"), CODE , start= 4, stop= 5))
```

But

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `CODE_SUB`.
x unused argument (CODE)

Comment: Try `replace(substr(df$CODE, 4, 5), df$ID != 'A', NA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ifelse` function inside `mutate`

```
df %>% mutate(CODE_SUB = as.numeric(ifelse(ID == "A", substr(CODE, start = 4, stop = 5), NA)))
```

Output

```
#   ID  CODE CODE_SUB
# 1  A 45676       76
# 2  B 87898       NA
# 3  B 89998       NA
# 4  A 45688       88
# 5  A 45556       56
```

Answer (score 2):

One `base R` solution could be:

```
with(df, (ID == "A")^NA * as.numeric(substr(CODE, nchar(CODE)-1, nchar(CODE))))

[1] 76 NA NA 88 56
```